# How to map elements from subgroup to larger subgroup of its parent group?

Tags: elliptic-curves, modular-arithmetic, group-theory, arithmetic

***The following context is based on elliptic curves in short-weierstrass form y^2 = x^3 + b.***

**pls read carefully-**

I am looking for a **function/formula/algorithm** that can be applied on any curve, *say for e.g.* *y^2 = x^3 + 2* with *prime = 1097, largest subgroup order(J) = 1098 and subgroups = 1098, 549, 122, 183, 366, 61 and so on.* Suppose I have a random generator point "A" (on subgroup 61) and multiply it with some *unknown scalar k* that gives point "B" (on subgroup 61). So how should I get corresponding points R and S in larger subgroup *J having order 1098* keeping the scalar k *preserved (k is unknown and not used in the process)*? You can think of a mapping of two points A and B from **H→J** where all properties are preserved along with scalar multiplication. **but** the resulting points R and S must belong to the larger subgroup J (which has order 1098) respecting scalar k.

***Key Points:***

1. **A, B ∈ H and R, S ∈ J *on E.C. y^2 = x^2 + 2 of prime = 1097***
2. **H** is cyclic subgroup of **order 61** and **J** is the large subgroup of **order 1098**.
3. Scalar **"k"** is **unknown** and should not be used for conversion **H→J**.
4. **A** is a *random generator point* on **subgroup H** of **order 61** and **B** is its **element** obtained from scalar multiplication **B = k*A** (on same subgroup H of order 61).
5. The cofactor **h = 1098/61 = 18**.
6. Brute force should not be used. We use only math.

**Our Goal: transform A, B ∈ H → R, S ∈ J while preserving scalar *k* (but NOT using k for conversion). This can be understood as the opposite of cofactor clearing or some mapping.**

***Sage Verification:***

```
p = 1097 
Fp = GF(p) 
E = EllipticCurve(Fp, [0, 2])

``
**YOUR TRANSFORMATION CODE HERE**
``

A.order() #result must be 61 
B.order() #result must be 61 
R.order() #result must be 1098 
S.order() #result must be 1098 

S == k * R #result must be 'True'
```

***A SAGE code for such transformation will be helpful.***

Comment: What was the problem with the answers in the previous question? (moderator note: [this one](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/revisions/108051/4). Both the present question and the other changed since then).

Comment: The question's field changed from $p=157$ in [rev 6](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/revisions/108069/6) to $p=1097$, making curve $E$ singular. That changes the problem markedly, and invalidates my detailed answer. While the cost to solve the problem for a nonsingular curve of cofactor $4$ was like $\mathcal O(\sqrt p)$ thus exponential in the size of $p$, that may no longer be the case. So we don't know what the general question is! I leave it to others to decide if this Q and [that one](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/108069/555) should remain open.

Comment: @fgrieu This question has all valid params and you may attempt to solve this. Apologies for many revisions.

Comment: @Homer: for small $p$ (up to millions), a solution is possible by enumeration, lacks cryptographic interest, and is thus off-topic. Implicitly, we want to tackle large classes of parameters. And you changed the class of parameters by changing $p$ from a value yielding a curve of order 4 times a prime where the DLP is hard and your problem (thus) intractable for large $p$, to one of order $p+1$ (and as an aside 18 times a prime) where this reasoning does not apply. I won't try to solve your problem until you specify some infinite but narrow class of curves, with clear and on-topic motivation.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the issue; any such efficiently computable mapping would allow someone to compute discrete logs in **H**, hence there is no such efficiently computable mapping for any subgroup of cryptographical interest.

Here are the properties I am assuming:

- There is an efficiently computable function $f$ that maps points in **H** to points in **G**
- $f$ has the property that $f(k \cdot G) = k \cdot f(G)$ for any $0 < k < h$ (where $h$ is the order of **H**)
- $f(G)$ has an order $> h$, that is, $h \cdot f(g) \ne 0$ (where $0$ is the point at infinity, aka the neutral element).

With those assumptions, given $kG$ (with $0 < k < h$), we can compute $f(k\cdot G)$ and $f(2 \cdot k \cdot G)$.  We have $f(2k \cdot G) = f((2k \bmod h) \cdot G)$ (because $G$ is of order $h$).

If $k < h/2$, then $2k \bmod h = 2k$, and so we have $f(2k \cdot G) = 2k\cdot f(G) = 2 \cdot f(k \cdot G)$, that is, doubling $f(k \cdot G)$ gives us $f(2k \cdot G)$

If $k > h/2$, then $2k \bmod h = 2k - h$, and so we have $f(2k \cdot G) = (2k-h) \cdot f(G) = 2f(k \cdot G) - h \cdot f(G)$.  Since $h \cdot f(G) \ne 0$, this is not $2f(k \cdot G)$, and so doubling $f(k \cdot G)$ gives us something other than $f(2k \cdot G)$

Hence, if $2 \cdot f(k \cdot G) = f(2 \cdot k \cdot G)$, then we know $k < h/2$; if $2 \cdot f(k \cdot G) \ne f(2 \cdot k \cdot G)$, then we know that $k > h/2$

With this efficient test for determining whether $k$ is on the left side or right side of $h/2$, we can use it $log_2 h$ times (via binary search) to determine the exact value of $k$, that is, solving the discrete log problem.

Comment: @fgrieu: if we insist that $f(k \cdot G) = k \cdot f(G)$ holds for $k=0$, your objection is correct.  I was specifically avoiding that case; if you don't insist on it, then such an $f$ can be defined (e.g. set $f(G)$ to an arbitrary generator in the group **G** (grumble, using $G$ to denote two different things), and to compute $f(kG)$, you solve the discrete log problem to recover $k$ and then return $k \cdot f(G)$.  That meets all the requirements; however it is not computable for large groups (and I endeavored to show that this is no alternative method which is much more efficient).

Comment: @Josh666: the point I was making is that the mapping you're asking for can be used to compute discrete logs, hence computing that mapping cannot be significantly more efficient.

Comment: @Josh666: "There must be an efficient method to perform such mappings because if cofactor clearing is possible then its reverse is also possible"; actually, we believe there exist mappings that cannot be efficiently inverted.  However, in this case, if we look at cofactor clearing $hA = B$, if we are given $B \in$ **G**, there are $h$ values of $A$ that solve it, and it is easy to compute that set,  What's not easy is selecting a single value from those $h$ values in a way that is consistent (in the way you specified); I just showed that doing that is hard assuming the DLP problem is hard

Comment: Can you write a sage example for your answer?

Answer (score 2):

**THIS ANSWER APPLIES TO [VERSION 6](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/revisions/108069/6) OF THE QUESTION**. It does not apply to [version 11](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/revisions/108069/11) which uses a different class of curves, with $p$ such that the curve's order is $p+1$.

---

We assume an elliptic curve $y^2=x^3+b$ over the field $\mathbb F_p$, with $p$ prime such that $p\bmod3=1$, and $b$ such that $b^{(p-1)/3}\bmod p=1$, and such that the corresponding elliptic curve group $G$ has order $h⋅n$ with $n$ prime and the cofactor $h=4$. Up to version 6, the question used such parameters: $p=157$, $b=2$, $n=43$.

Without proof: the group $G$ is the product of the cyclic group $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ of prime order $n$, and of the Klein 4 group $K_4$, which group law is:
$$\begin{array}{c|cccc}
+&0&u&v&w\\
\hline
0&0&u&v&w\\
u&u&0&w&v\\
v&v&w&0&u\\
w&w&v&u&0\\
\end{array}$$

Elements of $G$ can be classified according to their order, as:

- $1$ neutral/point at infinity $\mathcal O$, of order $1$. It's component in $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ and $K_4$ are $0$.
- $3$ points of order $2$, of coordinate $(x,0)$ with $x$ one of the three $x$ with $x^3+b\bmod p=0$. They are the elements of $G$ which component in $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ is $0$, and component in $K_4$ is $\ne0$.
- $n-1$ points of order $n$, forming (with $\mathcal O$) a uniquely defined subgroup $H$ of order $n$. They are the elements of $G$ which component in $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ is $\ne0$, and component in $K_4$ is $0$.
- $3⋅n-3$ points of order $2⋅n$. They are the elements of $G$ which components in $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ and $K_4$ are $\ne0$.

Notice that $\forall P\in G,\,(2⋅n)∗P=\mathcal O$. Also, if $P$ has order $2⋅n$, then $2*P$ has order $n$ and is a generator of $H$, and $n*P$ has order $2$.

In order to meet the question's "Verification Requirements", the question's $k$ must be odd. Proof by contraposition:

- Assume $k$ is not odd, and the verification requirements are met.
- Write $k$ as $k=2⋅j$. VR3 becomes $B′=(2⋅j)∗A′$
- The second part of VR1 tells $n∗B′\ne\mathcal O$
- Substitution yields that $n∗((2⋅j)∗A′)\ne\mathcal O$
- Rearranging yields $j*((2⋅n)∗A′)\ne\mathcal O$, using associativity and commutativity of integer multiplication $⋅$, and that $\forall u,v\in\mathbb Z,\,\forall X\in G,\, (u⋅v)*X=u*(v*X)$
- $(2⋅n)∗A′$ is $\mathcal O$ due to the aforementioned structure of $G$
- Substitution yields that $j*\mathcal O\ne\mathcal O$, which is false. Hence the original assumption is false.

More generally, in order to meet VR1 and VR3, $k$ must be coprime with the order of $G$.

For the "cofactor clearing function", we can pick any even $c$ coprime with $n$ and define function $g_c$ by $g_c(P)=c*P$. That $g_c$ is linear, and such that $\forall P\in G,\,g_c(P)\in H$. $c=2$ is the simplest. Another interesting choice is $c=n+1$, yielding function $\dot g$ with $\dot g(P)=(n+1)*P$, which has the property $\forall P\in H,\,\dot g(P)=P$. This cofactor clearing function $\dot g$ is projection on $H$, clearing the Klein Four-Group component of the input.

For the desired "inverse cofactor clearing function" $f$ such that $\forall P\in H,\,g(f(P))=P$, we can pick an element $S$ of order $2⋅n$, and construct $A$ from $S$ using our cofactor clearing function. Our $f$ will map $A$ to $S$, which passes the first requirement. Then the required linearity for $f$ (VR3) dictates what $f$ must do for many other inputs.

Here is Sage code for this:

```
p,b = 157,2                     # parameters for the curve
assert p in Primes() and p%3 == 1 and pow(-b,(p-1)//3,p) == 1
G = EllipticCurve(GF(p),[0,b])  # define the parent group
ordG = G.order()                # parent group order
n = factor(ordG)[-1][0]         # order of H
assert ordG == 4*n              # check cofactor is 4
O = G(0,1,0)                    # the neutral / point at infinity
c = n+1                         # cofactor clearing by projection (or c = 2)
ordS = 2*n                      # desired order for S
for S in G.points():            # search S 
    if S.order()==ordS:
        break
A = c*S                         # decide A
assert A.order() == n           # check the order of A (and H) is n
print("p =",p,"  b =",b,"  n =",n,"  c =",c,"  A =",A.xy(),"  S =",S.xy())

def clearing(P):                # our clearing function
    return c*P                  # multiply by an even constant coprime with n

def revclear(P):                # our reverse clearing function
    Q,R = A,S                   # A is to Q what S is to R..
    while Q != P:               # and throughout our search..
        Q,R = Q+A,R+S           # that remains, insuring linearity 
    return R                    # result found!

A2 = revclear(A)                # find A'
for k in range(1,n,2):          # check each possible (odd) k
    B = k*A                     # build B from k as specified
    B2 = revclear(B)            # find B'
    assert clearing(B2) == B, "revclear fails to reverse clearing"
    assert n*B2 != O            # requirement 1
    assert ordG*B2 == O         # requirement 2 (a tautology)
    assert B2 == k*A2           # requirement 3
print("all good")
```

The above matches the letter of "keeping the scalar $k$ preserved *(and unknown)*" prescription of the question: the function `revclear` is not given access to `k`.

However my `revclear` performs in the order of $\Theta(n)$ operations. I could reduce that to $\Theta(\sqrt n)$ (and make it less apparent that `revclear` sorts of finds $k$). Problem is, that's impractical for applications of cryptographic interest, where $n$ must be like 200-bit or higher. [This answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/108072/555) proves that there is little hope to find a practical method (note: this answer's $h$ is my $n$ rather than the $h=4$ in the question).

Comment: Also here we have to consider "Point order" aka "order of element".